# What is the right approach for Multi-tenancy using eclipselink

Tags: java, eclipselink, multi-tenant

Hello I'm developing a web application using Vaadin framework, JPA EclipseLink as ORM, MYSQL as database. Currently I'm working to implement Multitenant structure for my app. Here I've to choose TABLE_PER_TENANT with different schema in a shared database strategy as I already have some tenants.

Here is an example of my tenant specific entity:

```
@Entity
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA, contextProperty = PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {
......
}
```

Here is my persistence unit for tenant in persistence.xml :

```
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>Includes all tenant table class</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
            <!-- container isn upcloud ??-->
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Now I'm getting an entitymanager like this:

```
public static EntityManager createTenantSpecificEntityManager(){
        EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU").createEntityManager(getProperties());

        return em;
    }

private static Map<String, Object> getProperties(){
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", getDataBaseConnectionURL(COMPANY_NAME_AS_TENENT_ID));

        return properties;
    }
public static String getDataBaseConnectionURL(String schemaName){
        String str = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8";//for testing purpose
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        sb.insert(sb.indexOf("?"), schemaName);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Now I'm using entitymanager like this:

```
em = createTenantSpecificEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
       em.setProperty(EntityManagerProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, \COMPANY_NAME_AS_TENENT_ID);
.......
Do any operation here
.......
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

In the app user can log in to a specific tenant (where he has given the access). So at a time only one tenant's data can be accessed.

Is it the right approach for my app to make it Multi-tenant?
Is there any improvement I can do?

Answer (score 1):

One can use ThreadLocal as shown below:

```
public class TenantContext {
  private static final ThreadLocal<String> TENANT_TL = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static String getTenantId() {
    return TENANT_TL.get();
  }

  public static void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
    TENANT_TL.set(tenantId);
  }
}
```

The tenantId can be set on authentication, usually in an Interceptor. While creating EntityManager, above tenant can be used as shown:

```
em.setProperty(EntityManagerProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, TenantContext.getTenantId());
```

I have created a java example on Multi-Tenancy (Table per Tenant) using Eclipse Link and Spring Data. An existing application can be converted to Multi-Tenant with a minimal code change. This is done using bytecode instrumentation. This idea is chosen to utilize the complete power of Spring Data.

One can execute [MultiTenantTest](https://github.com/plummb/java-examples/tree/master/multitenant-jpa) to see it working.

The idea is open-sourced and is available at [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.swattu/jpa-agent)