# Does anyone know if EclipseLink supports database per tenant?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

We are currently using EclipseLink as our JPA implementation for the new code. The old code did multitenancy with the solution description as this: 
every customer (tenant) must have its own database - separate JDBC resources.
Information about selected tenant is carried across method invocations in ThreadLocal
TENANT variable, declared in com.aaa.Instance.java class.
JDBC resources are handled by com.aaa.TenantDataSource.
During initialization, TenantDataSource looks for DataSources registered
within java:comp/env/jdbc JNDI context and checks, if their names starts with 'abc_'.
References to DataSources are stored in internal map using tenant code from JNDI
resource name (DataSource named 'abc_xx' is registered as DataSource for 'xx' instance).
TenantDataSource examines value of Instance.TENANT variable when 'getConnection'
is invoked, for using appropriate DataSource.
TenantDataSource falls back to default DataSource if Instance.TENANT has null
value. This could be default behavior for single-tenant deployments.
Now we are using EclipseLink, I googled to see if I can implement multitenant as required. It seems EclipseLink can do:
 * Single-table multi-tenancy 
 * table-per-tenant
 * (VDP) multi-tenancy

not like Hibernate which supports database per tenant. 
Could someone tell if my research is right? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492375/what-is-the-right-approach-for-multi-tenancy-using-eclipselink ?

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek yes, that is exactly what I want to implement. Previously I thought we want to do database per tenant, after further reading the link you sent and talked to our dba, what we want is schema per tenant, which is table per tenant in EclipseLink. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll bump up this question. I'm looking for possible answer. Hibernate does have multitenancy with separate databases (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy). Eclipselink according to the docs (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm) does not have this type of multitenancy (only schema, table and VPD). We have legacy system using datamodel defined with eclipselink annotations (BatchFetch) and would like to use the same model definition on new web system with multitenancy.